How to add another column to a previous calculation showing frequency of values per year per month using dplyr in R
Issue
I have a large data frame (388 x 729) and I am trying to calculate the frequency of new daffodil bulbs (numeric column) per month (factor column) per year (numeric column) over 14 years.
I have successfully calculated the number of days that this experiment occurred per year per month from 2012 to 2024.
Now I want to add a column to show the frequency of new daffodil bulbs per year per month to the data frame previously created using the R-code (see below).
Is there a way to do both of these calculations together?
Many thanks in advance
Structure of Dataframe:
$Year               : num  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ... 
$ Month             : Factor w/ 18 levels "April","April ",..: 9 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 1 ...
$ Daffodil Bulbs    : num  0 3 0 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 ...

R-Code to Calculate the Number of Days this Experiment was conducted per year per month (2012 to 2024)
Frequency_Days_Experiment<-MyDf %>% mutate(Month = factor(trimws(Month), levels = month.name, ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
                                group_by(Year, Month) %>% 
                                count()

Dummy Code:
tibble(
       Month = sample(month.name, 120, replace = TRUE),
       Year = sample(2012:2024, 120, replace = TRUE),
       Number_Daffodils = sample(1:5, 120, replace = TRUE)
      ) 

Output from R Code
# A tibble: 96 × 3
# Groups:   Year, Month [96]
    Year Month        n
   <dbl> <ord>    <int>
 1  2012 January      1
 2  2012 February     8
 3  2012 April       18
 4  2012 May         21
 5  2012 June        27
 6  2012 July        12
 7  2012 October     12
 8  2012 November     4
 9  2012 December     3
10  2013 February     2
# ℹ 86 more rows

Desired Output
# A tibble: 96 × 4
# Groups:   Year, Month, Frequency_Daffodils [96]
    Year Month        n                    n   
   <dbl> <ord>     <int>                <int>
 1  2012 January      1                   25
 2  2012 February     8                    5
 3  2012 April       18                   13 
 4  2012 May         21                   45
 5  2012 June        27                    9
 6  2012 July        12                   78
 7  2012 October     12                   12
 8  2012 November     4                   62
 9  2012 December     3                    1
10  2013 February     2                    8
# ℹ 86 more rows


Instead of %>% count(), how about %>% summarise(N = n(), Bulbs = sum(Number_Daffodils))?

There are lots of great resources on the web to help learn R and the tidyverse. I strongly recommend you look through https://r4ds.had.co.nz. The chapter on summarizing data should be helpful. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise

@Limey, thank you! This worked! I really did appreciate your help

Here's the solution kindly given by Limey
New_Bulbs_Frequency<-MyDf %>% mutate(Month = factor(trimws(Month), levels = month.name, ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
                                group_by(Year, Month) %>% 
                                summarise(N = n(), New_Daffodils = sum(Frequncy_Daffodils))

